# How to return a value inside an if statement in a function

Tags: swift

I have gone through other similar questions to this but i still can't figure out how to get this value inside a statement from a function. I get 'Unexpected non-void return value in void function' error.

I want the copiedString value so i can use it elsewhere in my app.

```
func urlclipboardwatcher() -> String {
    let pasteboard = NSPasteboard.general

    var changeCount = NSPasteboard.general.changeCount

    Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.1, repeats: true) { _ in

        if let copiedString = pasteboard.string(forType: .string)  {

            if pasteboard.changeCount != changeCount {
              
                changeCount = pasteboard.changeCount
                
                if copiedString.starts(with: "https://") {
                    print(copiedString) //the final value i want to return
                    return copiedString   //where the error is showing
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your problem is not the `if` statement, your `return` is inside a closure. You should read into asynchronous programming in Swift.

Answer (score 1):

As EmilioPelaez already mentioned, your problem is that you mix synchronous and asynchronous code.
Your `func urlclipboardwatcher() -> String` is supposed to be synchronous. You expect that it will return a `String` after it has been executed.
However, it cannot, since it starts a `Timer` that returns `copiedString` only after it has fired. But your function has not been instructed to wait for this.
Thus, you have to convert your function from synchronous code to asynchronous code, which will change its signature from `func urlclipboardwatcher() -> String` to `func urlclipboardwatcher() async -> String`. How this can be done is e.g. decribed in [this blog](https://www.andyibanez.com/posts/converting-closure-based-code-into-async-await-in-swift/).
After such a conversion, you could wait for the new `func urlclipboardwatcher()` using e.g. `let clipboardString = await urlclipboardwatcher()`.